# Remove spaces in cells without text and numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code of this macro which removes leading and trailing spaces in cells with text or numbers:

```
Sub LIMPIAR()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 20628
Cells(i, 7).Value = Trim(Cells(i, 6).Value)

Next

End Sub
```

However , there are cells which its content is `"  "`. So I would like to convert that kind of cells to `""`. How Can I do that?

**EDIT:** I'm working with scraped data.

Comment: `Trim` should do what you want.  Are you sure that the spaces that don't dissapear are normal spaces and not non-breaking spaces?  Also, why are you adding a null string to the end of the cell contents?

Comment: I see that and Trim doesn't work in all cells. I'm working with scraped data. I really don't know what a non-breaking space is, and that could be the problem.

Comment: In the immediate window type `Print Asc(<cell with only spaces>)` and see what number you get.  If it's 160, trim won't work.

Comment: I got 160. You are right. Thanks, I'll learn a new concept and deal with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe dealing with them like this can help:

```
 If Len(Cells(i,6).Value) <= 2 Then Cells(i, 7).Value = "" End If
```

*OR*

```
 If Cells(i,6).Value = "  " Then Cells(i, 7).Value = "" End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a very elagent solution, but I would make use of the split function and then reconcatenate the elements of the resulting array. Assuming your string is in cell A1,

```
mystring = ""
myarray = Split(Cells(1, 1), " ")
For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
  If Trim(myarray(i)) <> "" Then
    mystring = mystring & Trim(myarray(i)) & " "
  End If
Next i
MsgBox Trim(mystring)
```

mystring should provide a string with just one space between words. You could put this code inside your loop.